# Kernel Source Code: What are parent_tidptr and child_tidptr in do_fork()?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, system-calls

On the above [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1733) what is meant by `parent_tidptr` and `child_tidptr` on `do_fork()` which creates a new process ?

Answer (score 5):

Let's start by looking at the raw system call interface. It varies a bit by architecture, but on x86-64 it is:

```
   long clone(unsigned long flags, void *child_stack,
              int *ptid, int *ctid,
              unsigned long newtls);
```

`ptid` and `ctid` are your `parent_tidptr` and `child_tidptr`. Now let's see what the [`clone(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) manual page has to say:

```
   CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
          Erase  the  child  thread  ID  at the location ctid in
          child memory when the child exits, and do a wakeup  on
          the  futex  at that address.

   CLONE_CHILD_SETTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
          Store  the child thread ID at the location ctid in the
          child's memory.

   CLONE_PARENT_SETTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
          Store  the child thread ID at the location ptid in the
          parent's memory.
```

These flags were primarily designed to implement threading libraries. If we take a look at the NPTL implementation of [`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) inside glibc, we eventually find code in [`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/createthread.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/createthread.c;hb=HEAD) that makes a `clone()` call that includes `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` and `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` in `flags`.

In that `clone()` call, we can also see that the `ptid` and `ctid` arguments *point to the same address*. (Remember that POSIX threads share an address space; this is accomplished with the `clone()` `CLONE_VM` flag.)

So, what's going on here is the following.

- `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` is being used to ensure that the kernel thread ID is being stored in a certain location in user space. The user-space side of the threading implementation needs to know that thread ID.
- `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` is being used to clear (i.e., zero) that same location when the thread created by `clone()` terminates.

Let's go a little further...

The thread ID that is returned via `ptid`/`ctid` is *not* the same as a POSIX thread ID (`pthread_t`), although in the 1:1 threading implementations such as NPTL, there is a one-to-one correspondence between kernel thread IDs and POSIX thread IDs. The kernel thread ID is the same ID you get by using the Linux [`gettid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) call. It's also returned by `clone()` as the system call return value, which prompts the question: why do we need `ptid`/`ctid`? The problem is that from the user-space side, things look like this:

```
tid = clone(...);
```

From the point of view of the user-space threading implementation, there's a race here, because the assignment to `tid` occurs only *after* `clone()` returns. This means that the user-space threading library may run into certain problems if it wants that information before the new thread does anything (like terminate, for example). Using `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` ensures that the new thread ID is placed in the location pointed to by `ptid` *before*
`clone()` returns, and thus allows a threading library to avoid such race conditions. (`CLONE_CHILD_SETTID` can also be used to similar effect.)

The reason that `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` is used to clear the `ptid`/`ctid` is to provide a way for a [`pthread_join()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) call in another thread to discover that the thread has terminated. In essence, the `ptid`/`ctid` location is being used as a *futex*, and the [`futex()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) system call is used to block, waiting for the integer at this location to change. (The details are a little convoluted, but `grep` for uses of `lll_wait_tid` and `lll_futex_wait` in the glibc source code. Ultimately, there is a `FUTEX_WAIT` operation taking place. Recall above that `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` does a futex wakeup on the target address.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and should be the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

`tid` stands for "thread id". The parameters `parent_tidptr` and `child_tidptr` point to user space memory in the parent process address space and child process address space, respectively. The newly created thread's id is stored in the int variables the pointers point to.

For more information, see the [`clone(2)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html).